# Magento update version

Tags: upgrade, composer

I'm currently running a Magento store version 2.3.0 and trying to upgrade it to version 2.3.2.

If I try to update on the Magento admin I receive the message bad credentials after entering the access keys. I believe the keys are correct.

And, if I try the update on the CLI when I run `composer update` command I get the 'Killed' message.

I've read that the killed message can occur if the server runs out of memory.

Our Magento store is hosted on a remote server which package includes unlimited SSD disk space and 2GB of RAM.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've since found out that the hosting provider hadn't correctly issued us with the correct amount of RAM.
I'm as of yet to find out what causes the 'Bad Credentials' error received from the admin update.